# Responsive table navigation bar with twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to create a navigation bar for my table using twitter bootstrap.

The end result would look something like this

[image]

Im trying to use bootstraps grid system for this and seem to have gotten the showing rows part to look as planned but cant get the buttons to be responsive when the user switches to mobile.

### HTML

```
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-8 col-lg-8"> <!-- controls !-->
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                            <a href="#">Back</a>
                        </div> 
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                            <a href="#">First</a>
                        </div>       
                       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                            <a href="#">Previous</a>
                        </div>   
                       <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                            <a href="#">Next</a>
                        </div>   
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
                            <a href="#">Last</a>
                        </div>   
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-4 col-lg-4"><!-- page number !-->
                        <div class="pull-right">
                            <span>Showing rows 1 to 10 of 20</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The buttons seem to only render on top of each other.

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9z2v7yp7/) showing whats happening.

Comment: Can I fix it creating a list?

Comment: @MattewDeveloper Sure so long as the solution is responsive im open to suggestions

Comment: Why don't you use bootstrap nav? http://getbootstrap.com/components/#nav or the pagination?

Comment: @user1655756 I think that might be one possible solution. But i dont know if it allows me to pull-right on the "showing rows" logic

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.
Anyway, your markup is wrong. Bootstrap cols must be preceded by a row. https://jsfiddle.net/9z2v7yp7/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about a button group?

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="...">
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Back</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">First</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Previous</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Next</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Last</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <span>Showing rows 1 to 10 of 20</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT added in showing rows and made more responsive on mobile devices

Comment: This is nice, i wasnt aware of the btn-group class. Now how do i handle the "showing rows" logic with this

Comment: actually testing this in the mobile view, this is not a responsive solution.

Comment: @Kendo added in the showing rows and took out the justified bit so it should be a bit more responsive

Answer (score 0):

Each of your button is wrapped in a div with a bootstrap class "col-sm-12" and "col-xs-12" . This means that each of those div will occupy 12 columns EACH, thereby leaving no column for other buttons or divs to lie on the same row.

To obtain the desired result, change their classes to "col-sm-2" so that each button's div occupies two columns out of twelve.